# I want to modify elements based on previous comments. Is it possible by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, comments, selector

The scenario is like below

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- Regular Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>

    <!-- Danger Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>
</div>
```

[image: The Scenario]

First, maybe I will get the comment through a part of word

```
$('.wp-block-buttons').each(function() {

    console.log($(this).parent().html().indexOf('Regular') >= 0);
});
```

And then, if the word exist, the next line of paragraph will be colored green or red whatever.

```
$("p").css("color", "green");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 *(Edit: Not my downvote)*

Comment: I've added the HTML for you, since it's really quite small. But please use copy and paste and provide markup as **text** next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but before getting to how to do it: If you can avoid post-processing the DOM based on *comment* nodes, it's much better to avoid it. If you can change the structure to output a class on the target `p` elements, for instance, that would be **much** better.

But it is possible. I don't know that jQuery really brings anything to the table here, though, as jQuery is very element-focussed and you're looking for non-element nodes (specifically comment nodes). But jQuery does provide the [`contents`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method, which gives you a jQuery object (array-like) that includes not just elements but also text and comment nodes. So you could get your container element's contents that way and loop through:

```
// Loop through the child nodes (not just child elements) of the container
$("#container").contents().each((_, node) => {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        $(node.nextElementSibling).css("color", "green");
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#container").contents().each((_, node) => {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        $(node.nextElementSibling).css("color", "green");
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- Regular Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>

    <!-- Danger Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the straight DOM version (no jQuery):

```
for (const node of document.getElementById("container").childNodes) {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        node.nextElementSibling.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
for (const node of document.getElementById("container").childNodes) {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        node.nextElementSibling.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- Regular Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>

    <!-- Danger Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I wouldn't directly set a style, though, I'd use a class:

```
for (const node of document.getElementById("container").childNodes) {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        node.nextElementSibling.classList.add("regular");
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
for (const node of document.getElementById("container").childNodes) {
    // If this is a comment node and it contains the word "Regular" and the
    // next *element* node is a paragraph, make it green
    if (node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE &&
        node.nodeValue.includes("Regular") &&
        node.nextElementSibling.tagName === "P") {
        node.nextElementSibling.classList.add("regular");
    }
}
```

```css
.regular {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- Regular Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>

    <!-- Danger Text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <button class="Download"></button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```